# AngularJS: load partial view into page dynamically

Tags: angularjs, partial-views

Creating my first AngularJS app.

A **ng-repeat**:er loads titles. Each title is clickable. When clicking a title, an ajax-call is getting more JSON data. I need to add this data below the clicked title.

The normal way, I would create the HTML as a string and append it to the source code. But since I'm using AngularJS, there should be a way to create a partial view with the HTML and another **ng-repeat** in it.

How can this be done?

Comment: That sounds like a good match for implementation of routing in your page. Take a look at this part of Angular's official tutorial: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07 and this documentation entry: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngView

Comment: Yes, this seem to be the best way. I was first thinking about not using routes, but this will do. One thing I don't understand is: how do you "append" a partial view into another partial view?

Comment: Take a look at `ng-include` directive: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude. With it you can include partials that can also have `ng-include` in them — having partials in partials and so on. And you can dynamically change the partial's source (by setting the url to some object reference rather than string literal — it's shown in the example of the documentation entry I've included).

Comment: Maybe have the view in a directive and then append the html of the directive as an element when you need it. That is if you truly do not want to preload the html and use ng-show/ng-hide.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a directive as per @Nicolas suggestion. Combining this with what @Andrew suggested you could do something like this.

Controller:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.items = [
        {id: 'a', subItems: []},
        {id: 'b', subItems: []}
    ];

    $scope.getSubItems = function(id) {
        $http.get('/sub-items/' + id)
            .then(function() {
                $scope.items.subItems = $scope.items.subItems.push(response.data);
            });
    }
});
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <a ng-click="getSubItems(item)">{{item.id}}</a>
  <list sub-items="item.subItems"></list>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('list', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          subItems: '=subItems'
        },
        template: '<ul>' +
            '<li ng-repeat="subItem in subItems">{{subItem.id}}</li>' +
          '</ul>'
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small example:  Your JSON is structured simply, with subItems array in each item's json object.

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $scope.items = [ {id: 'a', subItems: []}, {id: 'b', subItems: []} ];

  $scope.getSubItems = function(item) {
    $http.get('/sub-items/' + item.id).then(function(response) {
      //Append the response to the current list of subitems 
      //(incase some exist already)
      item.subItems = item.subItems.concat(repsonse.data);
    });
  };
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">

  <a ng-click="getSubItems(item)">{{item.id}}</div>
  <div ng-show="item.subItems.length">
    <h4>SubItems:</h4>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.subItems">{{subItem}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good solution, but I would prefer to use partial views to reduce the amount of generated HTML, also better structure in the app. This might come handy some other time though.

Comment: I would use a directive to do that.